# Correct route file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone help me to correct that?

```
match 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)', :via => [:get, :post]
```

This is working as expected if parameter :action is specified but if it is missing I get :action not found. Is it possible to have a default controller if **:action is missing** or **:id and :action** together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to use 'controller#action'. You can also only specify the controller there:

```
match 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs', :via => [:get, :post]
```